# Block of "if" statements is making my app hang

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a block of "if" statements that when they are activated they cause the app to become seriously slow or even hang.

Here is the block of code:

```
RoundedButton(
                  title: 'Save',
                  colour: Colors.blueAccent,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() {
                      showSpinner = true;
                    });
                    try {
                      // Save the Trxn
                      populateTrxnProvider();

                      ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider.notifier).saveTrxn(
                          ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider),
                          ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId!,
                          widget.newTrxn!);

                      // Add dates to calendar
                      if (bContractDate) {
                        bContractDate = false;
                        String title =
                            'Contract Date for ${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).clientLName}';
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventname(title);
                        String? desc =
                            '${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).propertyAddress} ${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).propertyCity}';
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventDescription(desc);
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventDate(
                                DateTime.parse(contractDateController.text));
                        AddEventsToAllCalendars.addEvent(
                            ref.read(eventsNotifierProvider));
                      }

                      if (bTwofouraSellerDisclosureDeadline) {
                        bTwofouraSellerDisclosureDeadline = false;
                        String title =
                            '24a Seller Disclosure Deadline for ${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).clientLName}';
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventname(title);
                        String? desc =
                            '${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).propertyAddress} ${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).propertyCity}';
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventDescription(desc);
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventDate(DateTime.parse(
                                sellerDisclosure24aController.text));
                        AddEventsToAllCalendars.addEvent(
                            ref.read(eventsNotifierProvider));
                      }
                      if (bTwofourbDueDiligenceDeadline) {
                        bTwofourbDueDiligenceDeadline = false;
                        String title =
                            '24b Due Diligence Deadline for ${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).clientLName}';
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventname(title);
                        String? desc =
                            '${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).propertyAddress} ${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).propertyCity}';
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventDescription(desc);
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventDate(
                                DateTime.parse(dueDiligence24bController.text));
                        AddEventsToAllCalendars.addEvent(
                            ref.read(eventsNotifierProvider));
                      }
                      if (bTwofourcFinancingAndAppraisalDeadline) {
                        bTwofourcFinancingAndAppraisalDeadline = false;
                        String title =
                            '24c Financing and Appraisal Deadline for ${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).clientLName}';
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventname(title);
                        String? desc =
                            '${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).propertyAddress} ${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).propertyCity}';
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventDescription(desc);
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventDate(
                                DateTime.parse(financing2cController.text));
                        AddEventsToAllCalendars.addEvent(
                            ref.read(eventsNotifierProvider));
                      }
                      if (btwofourdSettlementDeadline) {
                        btwofourdSettlementDeadline = false;
                        String title =
                            '24d Settlement Deadline for ${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).clientLName}';
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventname(title);
                        String? desc =
                            '${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).propertyAddress} ${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).propertyCity}';
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventDescription(desc);
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventDate(
                                DateTime.parse(settlement24dController.text));
                        AddEventsToAllCalendars.addEvent(
                            ref.read(eventsNotifierProvider));
                      }
                      if (bInspectionDate) {
                        bInspectionDate = false;
                        String title =
                            'Inspection Date for ${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).clientLName}';
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventname(title);
                        String? desc =
                            '${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).propertyAddress} ${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).propertyCity}';
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventDescription(desc);
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventDate(
                                DateTime.parse(inspectionDateController.text));
                        AddEventsToAllCalendars.addEvent(
                            ref.read(eventsNotifierProvider));
                      }
                      if (bAppraisalDate) {
                        bAppraisalDate = false;
                        String title =
                            'Appraisal Date for ${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).clientLName}';
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventname(title);
                        String? desc =
                            '${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).propertyAddress} ${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).propertyCity}';
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventDescription(desc);
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventDate(
                                DateTime.parse(appraisalDateController.text));
                        AddEventsToAllCalendars.addEvent(
                            ref.read(eventsNotifierProvider));
                      }
                      if (bClosingDate) {
                        bClosingDate = false;
                        String title =
                            'Closing Date for ${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).clientLName}';
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventname(title);
                        String? desc =
                            '${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).propertyAddress} ${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).propertyCity}';
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventDescription(desc);
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventDate(
                                DateTime.parse(closingDateController.text));
                        AddEventsToAllCalendars.addEvent(
                            ref.read(eventsNotifierProvider));
                      }
                      if (bFinalWalkThrough) {
                        bFinalWalkThrough = false;
                        String title =
                            'Final Walkthrough Date for ${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).clientLName}';
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventname(title);
                        String? desc =
                            '${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).propertyAddress} ${ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider).propertyCity}';
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventDescription(desc);
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventDate(
                                DateTime.parse(walkThroughDateController.text));
                        AddEventsToAllCalendars.addEvent(
                            ref.read(eventsNotifierProvider));
                      }

                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const CompanyDashboardScreen(),
                        ),
                      );
                      //Navigator.pop(context);
                      setState(() {
                        showSpinner = false;
                      });
                    } catch (e) {
                      // todo: add better error handling
                      //print(e);
                    }
                  },
                ),
```

I use the if statements to determine if a date has been set or changed in any of the textFields in the screen. Maybe there is a better way to do this.

If I take the if statements out of the code everything runs fine.

Why would these if statements cause the code to run slow?

Thanks